# JVM crashes with SIGSEGV when interacting with JavaFX webview using JDK11

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I'm hitting a rather strange error with javafx 11 and webview.
I was trying to set up a small proof of conecpt using OpenJDK 11.0.2 and OpenJFX 11.0.2.
I was loading a simple leaflet map and while the map loads fine, interaction with it (scroll, move, etc) results in the following error:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3d3740f27c, pid=3645, tid=4097
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.2+7) (build 11.0.2+7)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.2+7, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x8df27c]
```

I've also tried Oracle JDK 11 as well as the OpenJDK 12 EA build, with the same result. I've also tried running it under windows, directly from netbeans and the console, same result

If i use the same code with JDK 8, it runs fine.

The code is really just the following, fxml code omitted:

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private WebView mapView;
    @FXML
    private Pane webPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        mapView.getEngine().load("https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html");
    }
}
```

Is anyone hitting the same problem or knows how to debug this?
Sadly, i've found no information about this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Are you running it with Maven?

Comment: Make a bug report.

Comment: @JoséPereda Yes I'm running it with Maven

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Will do that

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/316) already reported when running JavaFX with Maven `exec:java`. Can you try running with `exec:exec` (see how to change the pom [here](https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/76))?

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks for the hint. I already found the issue when looking for the right place to file a bug. Running it with exec:exec works. Well, i never expected that maven might be the problem.